# Updating documents in mongodb

Tags: json, mongodb

I currently have documents in mongodb with the following format:

```
{ 
  "title": "name of the document",
  "tags" : ["tag1", "tag2", "tag3"]
}
```

I want to be able to search for all documents which have "search_term" in their title field and then append "search_term" into their tags field. Is there an easy/clean way to do this without re-ingesting all my documents or do I have to just write a script to do this before inserting them into mongodb all over again?

I did read the mongodb documentation for db.collection.update() which had examples like:

```
db.people.update(
 { name: "Andy" },
 {
   name: "Andy",
   rating: 1,
   score: 1
 },
 { upsert: true }
)
```

But this doesn't help me since I don't want to completely replace my "tags" field but rather append to it.

Comment: Something like `db.search.update({title: /.*search_term.*/}, {$push: {"tags": "search_term"}}, {multi: true})`. But since it's updating multiple documents, it won't be an atomic update

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
db.people.update(
    { "title": "search_term" }, 
    { "$push": { "tags": "search_term" } }, 
    { "multi": true }
);
```

In general I do migrations/changes over all data sets etc. in a script and run it from an admin route.

Explanation:

- First JSON: search filter
- Second JSON: push to the array
- `multi: true` if you want to update more than one doc

EDIT:
Since version `3.2` there is a function `db.collection.updateMany(filter, update, options)`which can be used to update multiple documents.

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/

```
db.people.updateMany(
    { "title": "search_term" }, 
    { "$push": { "tags": "search_term" } }
);
```

* *not tested*

Comment: I think my problem here is that the title field doesn't contain just the "search_term" but may contain combinations like "terms search_term terms" is there a way to match these cases?

Comment: Got it, used the query in the question comment, didn't see it until much later (Doh!) Thank you so much guys!

Comment: You should be using [`updateMany()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) by now.